# Quotients of compactly generated spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compactly generated Hausdorff space and let $\pi:X\to Y$ be a quotient map such that $Y$ is Hausdorff in the quotient topology. Is it true that every compact subset of $Y$ is an image by $\pi$ of some compact subset of $X$? If yes, is the Hausdorff assumption necessary? If not in general, is it at least true for a specific quotient map $\pi:X\to CX$ defining the unreduced cone of $X$?

Comment: If $X$ is paracompact, then $\pi$ is compact-covering. Note that the reverse implication holds: every compact-covering map surjecting onto a CGH-space is quotient. I think I have a counterexample to the general case of a quotient mapping onto the ordinal space $[0,\omega_1]$ which is not compact-covering.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks for the comment. I didn't know that this property has a name... It would be great to see that counterexample.

Comment: Actually, I think I found a counterexample for the quotient map defining the cone - that's theorems 5 and 6 in the paper "Continuity of the cone functor" by Roman Goebel.